# How add custom class name to ng-select2 container

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I would like add custom class name to `ng-select` container.

I have select element like below:

```
 <ng-select
    name="symbolPairsId"
    formControlName="symbolPairsId"
    id="symbolPairsId"
    [items]="setupTags"
    bindLabel="name"
    bindValue="id"
    [closeOnSelect]="true"
    [hideSelected]="true"
    multiple="true" ></ng-select>
```

and try to add custom class like this:

```
containerClass="success"
```

but doesn't work.what is the recommended way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-select does not have property called containerClass,
You can override default style by using class selector

**component.html**

```
<ng-select class="customClass"></ng-select>
```

**component.scss**

```
.ng-select.customClass ::ng-deep .ng-select-container  {            
    min-height: 0px;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

**[Reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select#:%7E:text=diffing%20the%20array.-,Custom%20styles,-If%20you%20are)**